# Converting Epoch to day of the week in new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a table with a column containing unix time. I wish to create a new column that contains the day of the week for this time. For example, 1436160600 would be a Monday in this column.

I have created a new column, entitled "day_of_week"

```
alter table master add column test varchar(20);
```

I now wish to update this new column with the appropriate values.

I found the MySQL Unixtimestamp() function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

I then attempted the following

```
update master set day_of_week = _sent_time_stamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp, %W));
```

where _sent_time_stamp is the column containing the Unix time values

But this results in an Error 1064.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. Convert epoch to date time

```
alter table master add column test_date datetime ;

update master set test_date = from_unixtime(_sent_time_stamp) ;
```

convert datetime to day of week using dayname function

```
alter table master add column test_day varchar(20) ;

update master set test_day = dayname(test_date) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but the accepted answer is sadly wasteful, and I hope that future people seeking this answer may be more enlightened.

No need to add a new column to the table just for some temporary value.  To achieve what you requested, you can simply do this:

```
UPDATE master
SET test_day = dayname(from_unixtime(_sent_time_stamp)) ;
```

However, even the goal is a wasteful in that we're simply storing two representations of the same data.  What you can do instead, is to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW master_vw AS 
    (SELECT mstr.*, DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(mstr._sent_time_stamp)) AS test_day
     FROM   master mstr) ;
```

Now, you can SELECT from this view anytime you like, and the value of test_day will always be in sync with the value of _sent_time_stamp.  And no new column to maintain and whatnot.

There is a use case for actually storing the test_day column - execution of the view will take a miniscule amount of additional processing versus selecting from a table.  And you cannot index over the virtual test_day column like you could in a table. So if you have millions of rows and you need to quickly get one that's (say) 'Saturday' then perhaps the table approach is more ideal.

But in cases where the column is just a convenience, or where it is simply a different representation of data that already exists, you'll do well to consider the View approach.